# How to reference aspx on subsite?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a sub asp.net site.  By sub, I mean it is a web app in IIS that is under the main web app.

When the user logs out of the main site, session variables remain valid on the sub site.

I'd like to null out session variables in the sub site.  I can create subendsession.aspx on the sub site specifically for this.  The main site calls endsession.aspx when the user logs out.  How do I call subendsession.aspx without redirecting the user there?

Is there a better technique for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

The `Abandon` method should work ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28VS.90%29.aspx)):

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: But how does the parent site get that executed on the sub site without a redirect?

Comment: `Server.Execute("subsitePage.aspx");`

Comment: That uses a virtual path.  These two sites are in different folders.  Sub site isn't a sub folder of main site.  How do I get the virtual path in that case?

Comment: I did figure out the virtual path.  When I execute Server.Execute(), I get an error in subsitePage.aspx: Could not load the type AppName.subsitePage.  Entering the URL path to subsitePage.aspx works fine.